# How to fix the Time on X axis skews from the data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

Here is my example for my time series data:

```
Time = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2022-02-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2022-02-05 23:00:00"), by = "1 hour")
Value = sample(c(1:12), 120, replace = TRUE)
Type = sample(c("A","B","C","D"),120, replace = TRUE)
test = cbind.data.frame(Time,Type,Value)
```

I have tried visual the Value by Type in the data with the code below.

```
test.all = ggplot(test, aes(x = Time, y = Value, colour = Type)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#0350d6","#03c615", "#03cfd6", "#9204b7"))+
  geom_line(size=1) +  
  theme_bw() + theme(legend.position = "bottom",legend.title=element_blank(), axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8, angle = 90),
                     axis.text=element_text(size=8, colour = "black"),axis.title.y = element_text(size=12),legend.text = element_text (size=12))+ 
  theme(panel.grid =  element_line(colour = "grey",size=0.2))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=60, vjust = 1.4, hjust = 1.4))+
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 2), nrow = 1))+
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2022-02-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2022-02-05 23:00:00"), by = "4 hour"), labels=date_format("%m-%d %H"),
                  limits = c(as.POSIXct("2022-02-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2022-02-05 23:00:00")),expand = expansion(mult = c(0.01,0.01)))
test.all
```

As you can see the results, the X axis does not start with the begining of time (02-01 00 as expected). It seem to skew about 15 hours to the right.

How should I fix this issue?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the time zone issue. You can set your time zone to local using `Sys.timezone` in the labels argument like this:

```r
Time = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2022-02-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2022-02-05 23:00:00"), by = "1 hour")
Value = sample(c(1:12), 120, replace = TRUE)
Type = sample(c("A","B","C","D"),120, replace = TRUE)
test = cbind.data.frame(Time,Type,Value)

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
test.all = ggplot(test, aes(x = Time, y = Value, colour = Type)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#0350d6","#03c615", "#03cfd6", "#9204b7"))+
  geom_line(size=1) +  
  theme_bw() + theme(legend.position = "bottom",legend.title=element_blank(), axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8, angle = 90),
                     axis.text=element_text(size=8, colour = "black"),axis.title.y = element_text(size=12),legend.text = element_text (size=12))+ 
  theme(panel.grid =  element_line(colour = "grey",size=0.2))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=60, vjust = 1.4, hjust = 1.4))+
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 2), nrow = 1))+
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2022-02-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2022-02-05 23:00:00"), by = "4 hour"), 
                   labels=date_format("%m-%d %H", tz = Sys.timezone(location = TRUE)),
                   limits = c(as.POSIXct("2022-02-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2022-02-05 23:00:00")),
                   expand = expansion(mult = c(0.01,0.01)))
#> Warning: Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` instead.
#> Warning: The `size` argument of `element_line()` is deprecated as of ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use the `linewidth` argument instead.
test.all
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>